# Cannot set breakpoint at Exit statement in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, debugging, breakpoints

I try to set the breakpoint at an Exit statement, like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 5;

  if I = 5 then
    Exit;

end;
```

But when the program starts, the breakpoint will become a red cross which indicates it is not available. Why? I am using the "Debug" version of the project and using "Run" button to debug the project.

Comment: I don't think you can put breakpoints on flow-control "procedures" like `Exit`, `Break`, and `Continue`. They are not real procedures, but more like keywords handled specially by the compiler. You can, however, put a breakpoint on the next suitable line above such a "procedure". [I suspect Embarcadero could choose to implement this functionality, but it might not be entirely straight-forward, and the need is maybe not that severe.]

Comment: In this instance you could put the breakpoint on the `end;` line

Comment: @KeithMiller: Indeed, but then -- of course -- you don't know *how* you got there.

Comment: It is possible that since there is no code after the **if clause** the code optimizer removed the exit statement before compiling as it has no purpouse in this specific code. Try adding some code after the exit and I'm pretty sure your breakpoint on `Exit` should work.

Comment: @SilverWarior: Not according to my tests in Delphi 10.3.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I currently don't have access to my development computer so I can't do any tests myself. But from expirience I know that usualy when you can put a breakpoint on certain line that is becouse code optimizer has thrown that line away as it figured out that it was not necessary.

Comment: Have you tried disabling optimizations and enabling all debug options on your project settings?

Comment: After looking at the code that OP posted I now see why breakpoint on his `Exit` cal doesn't fire. As far as compiler goes his `Exit` call is part of the code line that holds the if clause. So he wouldn't be able to step into it using breakpoint before if clause and the using F8 key for stepin one line at a time. Surrounding the `Exit` call with `begin..end` should allow that.

Comment: @SilverWarior "Surrounding the Exit call with begin..end should allow that." - it won't. Only adding some useless extra code such as an additional if will cause some instructions to be generated which you can place a breakpoint on.

Comment: You can normally set a breakpoint on `Exit` just fine. The issue here is the do-nothing code. As you initialize `I = 5;` and then test for `if I = 5`, and then immediately `Exit`, the compiler is smart enough to just remove the entire method body - it does nothing but `Exit`, which means it never needs to be called in the first place. You can't set a breakpoint in an entirely empty method or procedure either.

Comment: Untrue, @KenWhite. You can set a breakpoint on an empty method (as long as it hasn't been smartlinked out) on the BEGIN and END lines...

Comment: Also, @KenWhite, the compiler does not remove the code. It only removes the EXIT (as it is irrelevant here). The I:=5 and IF I=5 are compiled into MOV [EBP-8],5 and CMP DWORD PTR [EBP-8],5 (at least in DEBUG configuration - in RELEASE configuration, it is compiled as MOV EAX,5 and CMP EAX,5 instead, but still not empty)

Comment: You can set a breakpoint on an EXIT inside a function when used in the extended version accompanied by the function result like `Exit(True);`

Comment: @HeartWare: Setting a breakpoint on an empty method's `end`? Sure. Go ahead. What benefit does that provide? And yes, the compiler optimizes out that look (if optimization is on), because the code does nothing.

Comment: @KenWhite: Have you tried it? I have... The compiler does not optimize it away - it optimizes it to the two EAX statements. Try it out... And the empty method doesn't get smartlinked out as well, if it is attached to an event.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively to using a conditional breakpoint as suggested by HeartWare (the performance hit of that can be significant, depending on how often the code is being executed) you could change your code like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  I := 5;
  if I = 5 then begin
    asm nop end; // <== put breakpoint here
    Exit;
  end;
end;
```

This provides you with a convenient place to put the breakpoint.

Comment: I use that one as well :-)

Comment: Mine is "sleep(0)" ;)

Comment: I've always used Inc(NoOpCount), NoOpCount being a global variable.  Figuring that the compiler wouldn't optimize away a change to a global var...

Comment: Will that cause additional performance losses, including the speed and file size, due to such a nop statement?

Comment: Yes. The computer will spend 0.01µs longer per iteration (time estimate is probably wrong), but only when the condition is met :-). Seriously: No - not in any way that is measurable...

Comment: @HartWare is completely right: almost always the additional time is negligible. But out of the ASM NOP, sleep, and global variable methods, I suspect the sleep is by far the most "expensive" one, since it calls a function in the Windows API and 0 isn't "nothing" (see MSDN). But in practice, I think the best solution is not to alter the code at all and simply put the breakpoint on the closest possible line above the `Exit`, `Break`, or `Continue`. [Just for fun, I did some benchmarking using `QueryPerformanceCounter` and 10M loops: ASM NOP: 241187; Sleep: 9466812; Inc GC: 185641]

Comment: By "zero isn't nothing", I mean https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-sleep. (Couldn't add this link to the previous comment, because it got too long.)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the NOP uses much less CPU cycles than any of the other proposed dummy statements. Sleep calls an API function with all the overhead that entails, modifying a global variable means getting a pointer to it and reading and writing to that memory. But since we are talking about a debugging help, all that does not really matter. asm nop end is very simple to use and to memorize.

Comment: Another option would be an empty function declared as inline for release and not inlined for debug. That one would only generate code when compiled for debug. But that's way more complex.

Answer (score 4):

You can't (reliably) set breakpoints on EXIT (or CONTINUE or BREAK) as these are not statements in the normal sense.

You can, however, set a breakpoint on the IF line and then right-click on the red dot for that breakpoint, select Breakpoint Properties  and enter the same condition in the condition field as your IF statement:

[image: Conditional Breakpoint]

This will slow down the execution a little bit (more if that conditional breakpoint is within a loop), but will only activate the breakpoint if the condition is met (the breakpoint is actually halting the program every time it is hit, but if it has a condition set, the debugger will evaluate that expression and continue the execution without notifying you unless the condition is met).

Of course, this is a simplified example, but you can usually use conditional breakpoints in these cases to overcome the limitation of not being able to set the breakpoint on the exact EXIT statement.